# how impersonate user on Azure sql using Kerberos delegation

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

Please help me with Azure Sql Windows impersonation question

There is three-tier application that uses impersonation on service tier to connect to the MS SQL as user that has started the client application.

Kerberos ticket is used to impersonate client user on service like below:

```
SECURITY_HANDLE serverContext;

AcceptSecurityContext(ref inbound, ref serverContext, ref ClientToken, APIReference.ContextAttr, APIReference.SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP, out serverContext, out ServerToken, out uNewContextAttr, out NewLifeTime); // final handshake leg
ImpersonateSecurityContext(ref serverContext); //secur32.Dll

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=True") // works on MS SQL on premises

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Authentication=Active Directory Integrated"); // fails with Azure SQL (no impersonation is actually made)

RevertSecurityContext(ref _context); //secur32.Dll
```

However no user impersonation is made when Kerberos ticket is used for impersonation on Azure SQL (and works with MSSQL on premises).
The problem is that SQL queries are executed on AzureSQL under service user account instead of client user account.

Is it possible to get Kerberos ticket impersonation works with Azure SQL ?

I know that there is EXECUTE AS LOGIN functionality that can be used to impersonate user on Sql server. 
But I would like to get Kerberos impersonation working if it is possible.

UPD: I've used [adal.dll on service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#configure-your-client-computers) to connect the AzureSQL

I wrote c# code that impersonates on AzureSQL with `LogonUser` token and `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()` combination. However I'd like to use Kerberos delegation if it is possible

#### Upd

I did not find a way to impersonate user with Kerberos and to connect to the Azure SQL when service impersonated as user.

However I've user T-SQL `execute as user=` and `revert` commands to do database "impersonation"

Comment: You can add the Service User Account to the database group account so the application can access the database.  Normally when you create a SQL database you use windows credentials.  To Allow more than one user to access the database you create a group account and add users to the group.  The use the group account for allowing access to the database.  Or the other choice is just to add the Server Account as a new credential to the database.

Comment: @jdweng There are user and service accounts added to the database already. The problem is that I can't impersonate service to connect to the database as user if database is hosted on the AzureSQL.

Comment: You would have to ask the user to type a username and password and that is not very secure.  Why don't you want to use the Service Account?

Comment: @jdweng Kerberos delegation does not require password to be typed actually

Comment: Yes if you were using the login account credentials.  You do not want to use the Service Account credentials you want to the User Credentials which you cannot impersonate.